# Numerically integrating the density function of Brownian motion by matlab

Tags: numerical-methods, improper-integrals, matlab, numerical-calculus

I am going to evaluate the integral
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int^T_0 f(x,t) \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}}e^{-x^2/2t}dt$$

for some nice enough function $f$. The integrand has a very strong singularity at $t=0$. The function integral2 gives me warnings so often. Do we have some good function for an accurate answer?

Comment: If you know the spatial Fourier transform of $f$, then it's best to rewrite it in Fourier space for small $t$ where you do not have a singularity at $t=0$. Btw, is it really the integral of the product and not the convolution product that you are interested in (the latter is more common for applications)?

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment. It doesn't not come from the convolution, but it is a part of my computation of a Feynman Kac representation of some PDE solutions.